# Is a C++ reference to an object analogous to a double pointer in C?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference

I am reading "Accelerated C++" by Koenig. In chapter 5, Koenig defines a function which has a reference to a vector parameter. In the function body, a new vector is created and assigned to the parameter.

Is a reference to an object analogous to a double pointer in C?

I am imagining a local variable which is a pointer to a data structure on the heap (a vector in this case). The address of this variable (a double pointer) is passed to a function and, in the function body, is dereferenced and assigned the address of a new data structure on the heap (in this case, a new vector).

I realize references have different properties than pointers and that references are not necessarily implemented as pointers. However, is the above a reasonable way to think about things?

Comment: A referene is analogous to a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Don't think about references as pointers.  Best to think about them as aliases, since they don't even require any storage.  It's basically a "typedef for objects".

Comment: I think you're a little confused but not a million miles off. If you consider the reference as being analogous to a pointer and the vector as analogous to another pointer, then a reference to a vector is somewhat like a double pointer. But in the end, it's better to understand things in their own terms not by analogy.

Comment: You might find the more general term *indirection* useful.

Comment: @RSahu Thank you for your comment. I am confused as to how an object reference is analogous to a pointer and not a double pointer. I am thinking of objects as pointers to data structures on the heap. Perhaps that is where my confusion is stemming from?

Comment: @tossimmar, if you think of a local variable as a pointer to memory in stack, you will confuse yourself. Pointers, as types, have very specifi syntactic meaning in the language that are different from what you are thinking of for local variables.

Answer (score 5):

A pointer is *always* a separate value, that is in the case of:

```cpp
int x = 1;
int *y = &x;
```

There are two values here, `x` and `y`. These have different addresses such that:

```cpp
&x != &y
```

In the case of references it's just a *code alias*, not an actual separate thing, so:

```cpp
int x = 1;
int &y = x;
```

Where now you have two names for exactly the same thing:

```cpp
&x == &y
```

As `x` and `y` are from that point forward effectively interchangeable.

Remember that pointers *must* be de-referenced to be used. A reference requires no such special handling.

Where there's similarity is that a pointer *can* be used to manipulate a shared value, or a pointer-pointer to manipulate a pointer, but there is a level of indirection that makes it different.

In C where you don't have references you use pointers instead, so you have functions like this:

```c
void mutate(int* v);
```

Where that's a pointer meaning "mutable value", though in C++ it looks like:

```cpp
void mutate(int& v);
```

Comment: Thank you. Suppose we create an integer variable and assign it the value 1 as you did above. If I then call mutate on the address of the variable in C, a pointer is pushed onto the stack as part of the activation record of the call to mutate. What is pushed onto the stack if I call the C++ version of mutate? That is, I pass a reference to mutate instead of a pointer.

Comment: In C the address of the variable is involved. In C++ it might not be anything. One of the fantastic things about references is the latitude it gives the optimizer in the compiler. This could be left in a register and used inside that function, zero stack required, which isn't quite possible with a pointer.

Comment: These are good questions, but don't forget you can look at the assembly-level output of  a given program if you want to know what *actually* happens.

Comment: Was just about to. Much appreciated.